# Is there such a thing as a "fallback" DHCP server?

Tags: dhcp, ip-address

Suppose I have a network `10.0.0.0/24`, and a DHCP server that allocates addresses under that network.

My question is simple — I have a separate box which is also capable of acting as a DHCP server. However, I would only like it to serve addresses if the primary DHCP server is down, in effect acting as a "fallback" DHCP server.

Does the concept of a fallback DHCP server even exist? If it does, how would I go about setting one up on the backup server? Would my best course of action be to continously ping the main server and, upon some network failure, enable the backup?

This does seem a bit dirty, so are there any better solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about servers and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here.

Comment: My bad, @Cown. Which SE site would be more appropriate?

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to write that. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: And yes. Cown is right - that is more a server side question...

There is no such thing native to the protocol itself.

When a (or any) DHCP server hears a client's broadcast (either directly or through a DHCP relay service) with the DHCPDISCOVER message, it may choose to respond with a DHCPOFFER message. Multiple servers may each send their DHCPOFFER. It is entirely up to the requesting client which offer it chooses, and it will disclose its choice in the DHCPREQUEST message, by setting the chosen DHCP server's address in the corresponding field of the message. Usually, the servers that weren't chosen will then stay quiet and return the address they just offered to their pool.

Setting up a failover mechanism between DHCP servers is probably a bit too much. And besides: Pinging a server to determine its liveliness yields results of very limited accuracy. The server's IP stack may respond to ping requests all the time, but that doesn't say anything about the DHCP service running on that server, which might be down, in disarray, misconfigured, out of addresses...

To have more than one DHCP servers serving requests from a single subnet, there's basically two ways to approach the issue:

- use a product that keeps the state of leased-out addresses in sync
  across all involved server instances, so that if one server goes down, the other
  won't offer an address that was already leased to a client by another one.
- keep servers instances running independently, while making sure the address ranges they serve don't overlap. To pick up your example: Server A would offer addresses from 10.0.0.[64-127], server B from 10.0.0.[128-191]. The rest of the subnet's parameters and options (router address, network address, subnet mask, name server, boot server, NTP server etc.) are configured identically on both servers. [1]

Eventually, in both cases, both servers will DHCPOFFER, but the client will DHCPREQUEST only one. In the first case, only one server will DHCPACK, but both servers will know about the lease (via their proprietary sync mechanism). In the second case, each server will only know about and keep track about the own leases.

---

[1] Along with that, you might want to set a DHCP lease time long enough to cover a server's time-to-repair-plus-some, so that the client's leases don't expire and they don't have to renumber while the server that had given them their address is being restored.